# Handle asynchronous messages in ejabberd

Tags: java, android, ejabberd, smack

I have [ejabberd](https://www.ejabberd.im/) as my local server and [smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/) as the android side api.

When user comes online and there is number of offline messages to deliver , the ejabberd server just floods me with the messages .and i get every message but the order is just not perfect. ***the order in which message is sent and saved in server is not how i receive the messages.***

I can handle the offline messages on smack by the [OfflineMessageManager](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/3.4.0/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/OfflineMessageManager.html) class . but this is not supported in ejabberd. i used [supportsFlexibleRetrieval()](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/3.4.0/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/OfflineMessageManager.html#supportsFlexibleRetrieval()) to check it and it returned false.

I also checked it with the [Xabber](https://www.xabber.com/) android app and surprisingly here i get all the messages in correct order from the ejabberd server. so the problem is at my android client side. my receiver is as follows-

```
PacketListener myListener;
String new_msg_body, new_msg_from;

final StanzaFilter filter = new AndFilter(new StanzaTypeFilter(Message.class));

        PacketCollector myCollector = conn1.createPacketCollector(filter);

        myListener = new PacketListener() {
            @Override
            public void processPacket(Stanza packet) throws SmackException.NotConnectedException {
                Message msg = (Message) packet;
                new_msg_body = msg.getBody();
                new_msg_from = msg.getFrom();
                Log.i("log", "message recived :" + new_msg_body + " from : " + new_msg_from +" msg id : " + msg.getStanzaId());
            }
        };

        conn1.addPacketListener(myListener, filter);
```

*Do any one have any suggestion for this problem.*

***Progress***

Till now i have found that each message has its `id` and the ids of each message is in order if their sending time. so i can may be do a sorting here to get the messages in order.

got to know that each packet that comes that fires its own receiver instance. and this will make the device flood with number of messages at a time . this might be causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

ejabberd 16.02 or latest version  support  Flexible Offline Message Retrieval (XEP-0013) .download and install latest version of ejabberd. [check this link](https://www.ejabberd.im/forum/25396/ejabberd-1602-happy-leap-day)

Comment: hey . thanks for your reply. can you tell me how to get the current version of ejabberd server i am using ?

Comment: you can get version using  sudo  ejabberdctl status output----
The node 'ejabberd@localhost.com' is started with status: started
ejabberd 16.02 is running in that node

Comment: sudo ejabberdctl status (works if installed from source) otherwise use  like that in my case sudo /opt/ejabberd-16.02/bin/ejabberdctl status

Comment: will give it a try .

Answer (score 0):

XEP-0013: Flexible Offline Message Retrieval is from 2003, maybe it is time to move to the much more modern [XEP-0313: Message Archive Management](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html)? It is far better for multiple devices environments, such as the concurrent use of mobile and web apps.

[MongooseIM](https://github.com/esl/MongooseIM) has a strong support for [MAM](http://mongooseim.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/mod_mam/): MongooseIM 1.6.2 supports MAM v0.2, but our master branch (next version) supports MAM v0.5.1. You can store your message archive in MySQL, PostgreSQL, Riak KV, and Cassandra!

Comment: XEP-0013 and XEP-0313 solve different problems. The questioners problem is solved by XEP-0013, and not XEP-0313.